# Broker that allows percentage-based trades

Tags: online-brokerage

Is there a broker available that allows you to place trades based on a percentage of your account? For example, I buy 5% if x stock price hits and sell 5% if y stock price hits.

Most brokers base trade executions on number of shares only.

Comment: Questions seeking product/service recommendations are off-topic. Sorry.

Comment: In this day and age of sophisticated algorithmic orders (available from retail brokers who offer them), a 5% order is a blunt instrument.  How hard would it be to calculate 5% of your account's value?

Comment: What if you don't have 5% cash in your portfolio?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, most serious brokers provide an interface where you can enter the order size in various ways and let it calculate the exact amounts for you. There are exceptions, like Robinhood, which is why sometimes people don't consider RH a serious broker. There are also non-brokerage service that provide this feature. For example, I use a free and open source one called [Qalculate](https://qalculate.github.io/).

On a serious note, no, it is not common to allow percent orders. The value of your account may change rapidly which will result in a lot of bookkeeping on the order. Moreover, exchanges maintain order books which would become vastly more chaotic if sizes of individual orders were not constant. It would create chaos on the markets, and besides, the additional work of such an order would not justify the $8 commission you are paying. There may be some robo-advising services that will automatically balance your portfolio at intervals, and the pros of course pay thousands to have API access and write their own balancer, but as an individual you either have so little money that it's not much work to do the math yourself manually, or you have so much money that you can afford to hire someone to do it for you. You can also just buy an ETF or even mutual fund that will do the rebalancing for you without having to explicitly hire anyone, but of course not every portfolio strategy has a good fund.